# Is TRUE equal to one (TRUE=1?) or greater than one (TRUE>1?) or even sometimes equal to zero (TRUE=0?)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The title of this question seems weird, let me explain what I mean.

In B) below, it turns out that TRUE>1 because it returns TRUE; however, TRUE+0 returns 1, which means that TRUE=1. Thus, TRUE sometimes is greater than 1 and sometimes equal to 1.

In A) we can see that the same happens with FALSE, it may be FALSE>0 as in the first line, and FALSE=0 as in the second line.

Returning to the calculations, in C) we can see that TRUE=0 since it is not counted by the SUMPRODUCT function.

All this confuses me a great deal, and I constantly have to check if excel is calculating properly or not.

My conclusions so far:

1. in a simple comparison (+, -, =), TRUE>1 because its type is 4 (type of 0 is 1).
2. in a simple comparison (+, -, =), FALSE>0 because its type is 4 (type of 0 is 1).
3. TRUE and FALSE, preceded by a unary +/- remain logical values (TRUE>1 and FALSE>0)
4. when used in an arithmetic binary operation (+, -, ...) TRUE is coverted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0 (TRUE=1 and FALSE=0)
5. for some functions, such as SUMPRODUCT in C), TRUE is not counted (TRUE=0)
6. FALSE (type 4) > ="" (type 2) > 0 (type 1); also, due to transitive property, FALSE (type 4) > 0 (type 1)

Please see the results in the picture below.

[image]

There is more to this subject, please have a look at the following picture:

[image]

1. an empty cell is equal to ="" (double quote), to zero (0) or even to FALSE
2. however, "double quote", zero and FALSE are not equal among them; it seems to me that the transitive property is not respected

I do not want to make this question too long.

I'd like to know if you agree with my conclusions and if you have other similar cases where the mathematical logic is in conflict with the results that excel yields

Comment: If you put in E10 sumproduct(C10,D10) then the results are different, compared to your sumproduct(C10:D10)

Comment: If you want "proper" calculation according to mathematical logic, then you're best off not involving `TRUE` and `FALSE` in arithmetic in the first place, as those results are mathematically meaningless. Use `IF` to convert logical values to numbers as appropriate and don't rely on Excel's internal conversion logic (which is indeed rather arcane).

Comment: The main bugaboo seem to be comparisons between logical values and non-logical values. These consistently yield that both `TRUE` and `FALSE` are "greater" than any non-logical value (as far as I can tell, I haven't tested special things like infinity). Arithmetic functions ignore the logical values, as if the cells were empty (most convincingly established with `AVERAGE`). Only for simple binary arithmetic is there a conversion of `FALSE` to 0 and `TRUE` to 1, but, as mentioned, I wouldn't rely on even that and just use `IF`.

Comment: You have to add the double unary operator `--` when calculating with `TRUE` or `FALSE`, e.g. `=--FALSE > 0` or `=SUMPRODUCT(--(C10:D10))` will return the expected results.

Comment: @Ike: that's not a separate operator, it's just the regular negation operator, applied twice. `0+` or `1*` would have the same effect, in that all involve identity operations converting the values to numbers.

Comment: (If you change the comparisons operators to <, >, =) I agree with your 6 points **except** at the end of 5th. 5. itself is correct (`SUMPRODUCT` only takes care of numbers, type=1 so TRUE is not "counted"); however, it does **not** imply that TRUE is 0 (or whatever numeric value). It is just not taken into account for the functions which exclusively consider numbers.

Comment: Regarding the second list, it appears so because "empty" is not a value within Excel. For the purpose of evaluation of formulas, it is _replaced_ (with the 0-value equivalent for the relevant context, that is, `0` or `""` or `FALSE`.) Similarly, you cannot define the _type_ of "empty".